# testRegex mask picks wrong files to run tests

Tags: reactjs, configuration, jestjs

**Update on 2018/07/13:**

After hacking around, I figured out why the `testRegex` didn't work. See my own answer posted below.

---

**Original Question:**

I am writing the test code for my React.js project. I'm using `react-scripts` and `enzyme` (which I believe implies `jest` as well) to run and manage the tests. Here is the `package.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "front",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "~15.5.4",
    "react-dom": "~15.5.4",
    "react-scripts": "0.9.5",
    "redux": "~3.6.0",
    "react-redux": "~5.0.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "enzyme": "^3.3.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-15": "^1.0.6",
    "react-test-renderer": "~15.5.4"
  },
  "jest": {
    "testRegex": "(/abc/.*|(\\.|/)(defg|spec))\\.jsx?$"
  }
}
```

After `npm install`, I checked the versions:

- react-scripts@0.9.5
- enzyme@3.3.0
- jest@18.1.0

(Yeah, I know I'm using an older version of React.js but that's what I can't change right now because it is not my personal project.)

**What I don't understand** is the `testRegex` of `jest` doesn't work as I expect. Currently, I put all my test files under `__tests__` folder and name them as "something.test.js". However, if you look at the `testRegex` above, firstly, it doesn't look for `__tests__` but `abc` as the folder name and, secondly, it doesn't look for `test` but `defg` as the file name.

Because of the configuration above, I was expecting my test files wouldn't be executed at all. However, when I ran `npm test`, the test files were still executed.

**What did I do wrong?**

Some of my thoughts:

- `jest@18.1.0` may not support the `testRegex`.
- I may need to configure `jest` via `react-scripts` but its user guide seems to show that I can just configure jest the way I'm doing (putting a "jest" section in package.json).
- I also tried to use the latest `jest` v23.3, but it still didn't work as I expected.
- I am aware of `testMatch`, but the documentation says ["note that you cannot specify both options"](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/22.0/configuration#testregex-string), so I am assuming that if I have specified `testRegex` in `package.json`, `testMatch` is ignored. Is this true?

Comment: Your answer might be correct, but isn't your regex also wrong?
I had the same regex pattern, and the solution was to remove one pipe character (the one after the star), replacing (/abc/.*|(\\.|/)(defg|spec))\\.jsx?$ with (/abc/.*(\\.|/)(defg|spec))\\.jsx?$

Comment: @Juvaly Hmm.. Are you also using `react-scripts` to run the tests? I think both our regular expressions work (I tested them on https://regexr.com/), but if you use `react-scripts`, the regular expressions may not be used to override the [default one](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#testregex-string) so it is not effective.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After hacking around, I realized it is because `testRegex` cannot be overridden if you use [`react-scripts`](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/tree/v0.9.5/packages/react-scripts/scripts)(note it is the link to the tag `v0.9.5`) to run the tests, in either the older or the latest versions (By the time I posted this answer, the latest version of `react-scripts` was `1.1.4`).

Here are more details.

In my original question above, I was using [`react-scripts v0.9.5`](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/tree/v0.9.5/packages/react-scripts/scripts). When I ran `CI=true npm test` to run the test, it was [`react-scripts/scripts/test.js`](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/v0.9.5/packages/react-scripts/scripts/test.js) that was actually run. This is a wrapper script that eventually still calls `jest`. In [this line](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/67d04032a3e4d8d4d44c395e7fe291e0d9a381c8/packages/react-scripts/scripts/test.js#L36), it creates Jest configuration and passes into `jest` as its `--config` options:

```
argv.push('--config', JSON.stringify(createJestConfig(
  relativePath => path.resolve(__dirname, '..', relativePath),
  path.resolve(paths.appSrc, '..'),
  false
)));
```

Tracking down the `createJestConfig` function in [this file](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/v0.9.5/packages/react-scripts/utils/createJestConfig.js), you'll see it creates some of the Jest configuration items and returns them as a JavaScript object.

Therefore, `jest` (I'm using `18.1.0`) is eventually run with a `--config` option that has a stringified JSON string.

If you trace down `jest.run`, it eventually comes to [this `runCli` function](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/v18.1.0/packages/jest-cli/src/jest.js#L282)(this is a link to `v18.1.0`) which reads the configuration [here](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/v18.1.0/packages/jest-cli/src/jest.js#L282), and this `readConfig` function is [imported from `jest-config` module](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/v18.1.0/packages/jest-cli/src/jest.js#L32).

Then let's look at the `jest-config` module. The aforesaid `readConfig` is defined in [this file](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/v18.1.0/packages/jest-config/src/index.js).

The `readConfig` function calls `readRawConfig` and then includes the configurations set from `argv` by calling `setFromArgv`:

```
const readConfig = (argv: any, packageRoot: string) =>
  readRawConfig(argv, packageRoot)
    .then(config => Object.freeze(setFromArgv(config, argv)));
```

Here is the `readRawConfig` implementation with my comments (preceded with "ywen") about what the lines do:

```
const parseConfig = argv => {
  if (argv.config && typeof argv.config === 'string') {
    // If the passed in value looks like JSON, treat it as an object.
    if (argv.config[0] === '{' && argv.config[argv.config.length - 1] === '}') {
      return JSON.parse(argv.config);
    }
  }
  return argv.config;
};

const readRawConfig = (argv, root) => {
  // [ywen]
  // Calls the `parseConfig` above. Remember that react-scripts's
  // test.js passes in the configuration as a stringified JSON
  // string, so the "If the passed in value looks like JSON..."
  // test is met. The stringified JSON string is read and parsed
  // back to a JavaScript object, returned, and stored in the
  // rawConfig variable.
  const rawConfig = parseConfig(argv);

  if (typeof rawConfig === 'string') {
    return loadFromFile(path.resolve(process.cwd(), rawConfig));
  }

  if (typeof rawConfig === 'object') {
    // [ywen]
    // Because `rawConfig` is a JS object, this if branch is
    // executed. The function returns with the normalized
    // configuration, so the `loadFromPackage` function, which
    // reads the `jest` configuration from the `package.json`,
    // is **NOT** called.
    const config = Object.assign({}, rawConfig);
    config.rootDir = config.rootDir || root;
    return Promise.resolve(normalize(config, argv));
  }

  return loadFromPackage(path.join(root, 'package.json'), argv).
  then(config => {
    console.log('package.json config: ', config);
    config || normalize({ rootDir: root }, argv)
  });
};
```

The [`setFromArgv`](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/v18.1.0/packages/jest-config/src/setFromArgv.js) overrides the configuration with those provided on the argv, but `testRegex` is **NOT** one of them.

If you provide your own `--config` on the command line such as `CI=true npm test -- --config ./jest.config.js /path/to/your/test/file.js`, there will be two `--config` items added to the `argv` passed to jest: one is provided by you, the other is (secretly) created by react-scripts's `createJestConfig`. They are grouped as a list in `argv.config`:

```
  config: 
   [ './jest.config.js',
     '{"collectCoverageFrom":["src/**/*.{js,jsx}"],...'
   ],
```

When the `parseConfig` is called by `readRawConfig`, the `if (argv.config && typeof argv.config === 'string') {` test fails because the passed in value is a list, not a string. As a result, the `parseConfig` returns this list as-is. This list is then stored in `rawConfig`. The type of `rawConfig` is still `object`. But in the line `const config = Object.assign({}, rawConfig);`, it is transformed into something as follows:

```
{ '0': './jest.config.js',
  '1': '{"collectCoverageFrom":["src/**/*.{js,jsx}"], ...
}'
```

which will finally fail at [this line](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/v18.1.0/packages/jest-config/src/normalize.js#L414) because `0` or `1` is not a valid Jest configuration.

As a result, when using `react-scripts v0.9.5`, its `test` script does not support the customization of `testRegex`.

This is still the case in `react-scripts v1.1.4` which is the latest version by the time of this writing. The [`createJestConfig.js`](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/v1.1.4/packages/react-scripts/scripts/utils/createJestConfig.js): it allows [some of the keys to be overridden](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/v1.1.4/packages/react-scripts/scripts/utils/createJestConfig.js#L60), but `testRegex` is still not one of them.

Comment: My react-scripts is 3.4.0 and it's still there. Thanks for awesome investigation!

Answer (score 1):

try this:
create a separate file named jest.config.js

```
module.exports = {

  coverageDirectory: "coverage",

  moduleFileExtensions: [
   "ts",
   "tsx",
   "js"
  ],

  testEnvironment: "node",

  testRegex: "(/__tests__/.*|(\\.|/)(test|spec))\\.(jsx?|tsx?)$",

};
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but this doesn't work. See my own answer.

Answer (score 1):

why don't you try using the [`testMatch`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#testmatch-array-string) option only?
if you have `jest.config.js` file just write this:

```
const path = required('path)

module.exports = {
  rootDir: path.join(__dirname, './'),
  roots: [path.join(__dirname, './abc')],
  projects: [
     {
       displayName: 'Functional',
       testMatch: [ '**/__tests__/**/*test.js?(x)' ]
     },
     {
       displayName: 'Integration API ',
       testMatch: [ '**/__tests__/**/*spec.js?(x)' ]
     },
  ]
}
```

and your test files looks like

```
    ├── abc/ 
    │  │__tests__/
    │    ├── login.spec.js # test
    │    └── anything.txt # not test
    │    └── method.test.js # test
    │
    ├── package.json # not test
    ├── server.js # not test
    └── jest.config.js # not test (this your jest config)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply and the information! Appreciate it! I should have clarified earlier that the intention of the question was to understand why `testRegex` didn't work instead of finding a solution for my project.

Comment: Although, for some complex cases, you are better off with a regex. If you want jest to only test files that start with a `xxx` and have exactly three numbers in fixed places ánd the filename ends with .test or .jest, go for a regex. But don't do that anyway.